# In the Python debugger, how to step into the second method call on a line?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb, ipdb

I'm trying to debug something in Django, and at some point in `ipdb` I ended up at the following stack trace:

```
ipdb> u
> /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/dashboard/views/base.py(191)get()
    190     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
--> 191         self.object = self.get_object()
    192         return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I would like to step into the call to `get_object()`. However, if I type the `s` command, it steps into the `self.object` call (which is the `__get__` method of the object, Django view):

```
ipdb> s
--Call--
> /Users/kurtpeek/.local/share/virtualenvs/lucy-web-CVxkrCFK/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py(176)__get__()
    175 
--> 176     def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
    177         if instance is not None:
```

Is it possible to step into the second method call on the line, not the first one? I've tried perusing the commands on https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can step into the first function with ‘s’ And then run to the end of the function with ‘r’. From there you should be able to step into the second function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Django agnostic example with the run through the actual steps. Want to over-communicate what @Jason pointed out. It took me a while to get it working even though the instructions are correct as long as followed literally.

```
#example.py
import pdb

def fun_a(arg_a):
    res_a = arg_a + "-a"
    return res_a

def fun_b(arg_b):
    res_b = arg_b + "-b"
    return res_b 

def fun_final(res_a, res_b):
    res_final = res_a + res_b
    return res_final

pdb.set_trace()
fun_final(fun_a("first"), fun_b("second"))
```

Running the debugger:

```
python3 example.py
[0] > .../example.py(16)<module>()
-> fun_final(fun_a("first"), fun_b("second"))
(Pdb++) s
--Call--
[1] > .../example.py(3)fun_a()
-> def fun_a(arg_a):
(Pdb++) r
--Return--
[1] > .../example.py(5)fun_a()->'first-a'
-> return res_a
(Pdb++) s
--Call--
[1] > .../example.py(7)fun_b()
-> def fun_b(arg_b):
(Pdb++) r
--Return--
[1] > .../example.py(9)fun_b()->'second-b'
-> return res_b
(Pdb++) s
--Call--
[1] > .../example.py(11)fun_final()
-> def fun_final(res_a, res_b):
(Pdb++) ll
  11  -> def fun_final(res_a, res_b):                                                                                                                                                                              
  12         res_final = res_a + res_b                                                                                                                                                                             
  13         return res_final
```

**You have to press `s` after `r` even if the active line shows `return res_a`. Don't expect to see `fun_final(fun_a("first"), fun_b("second"))` besides the initial step.**